# Batch program to xcopy from host PC to remote destination with multi-processing

Tags: python, optimization, python-3.x, csv, multiprocessing

This is a batch program to xcopy from host PC to remote destination with multi-processing.

Kepler, Python-3.x are my environment.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# based on Carnival http://ask.python.kr/users/6970/carnival/

import os
import os.path
import csv
import re

from multiprocessing import Process, Lock

class Server:
    def __init__(self, addr, path):
        self.addr = addr
        self.path = path

def distribute_file(server_list, pathname):
    print("Read from {}".format(pathname))  

    with open(pathname, 'rb') as inFile:
        buffer = inFile.read()

    for server in server_list:
        remotepath = "//%s/%s/%s" % (server.addr, server.path, pathname)
        print ("Write to {}".format(remotepath))
        with open(remotepath, 'wb') as outFile:
            outFile.write(buffer)

def multi_distribute_file(lo, server, dirpath, filename, path):
    lo.acquire()

    pathname = os.path.join(dirpath, filename)    
    print("Read from {}".format(pathname)) 

    with open(pathname, 'rb') as inFile:
        buffer = inFile.read()

    if(path == ''):
        remotepath = "//%s/%s/%s" % (server.addr, server.path, filename)
    else:
        remotepath = "//%s/%s/%s/%s" % (server.addr, server.path, path, filename)

    print ("Write to {}".format(remotepath))
    with open(remotepath, 'wb') as outFile:
        outFile.write(buffer)

    lo.release()    

def make_dir(server_list, path):
    for server in server_list:    
        dirpath = "//%s/%s/%s" % (server.addr, server.path, path)
        d = os.path.dirname(dirpath)
        if not os.path.exists(d):
            os.makedirs(d)
            print ("Make dir {}".format(d))         
        else:
            print ("dir {} already exists.".format(d))

        if not os.path.exists(dirpath):
            os.makedirs(dirpath)
            print ("Make dir {}".format(dirpath))          
        else:
            print ("dir {} already exists.".format(dirpath))

def dist_files(server_list, subdir):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(subdir):     

        l = re.findall(r"[\w']+",subdir)
        m = re.findall(r"[\w']+",dirpath)        
        path = ''
        if(l != m):
            path = m[len(m)-1]

        make_dir(server_list, path)            
        for filename in filenames:
            for server in server_list:
                lock = Lock()
                Process(target=multi_distribute_file,args=(lock, server, dirpath, filename, path)).start()                                

def get_server_list(filename):    
    mydictionary = []
    csvFile = csv.reader(open(filename, "r"))
    for row in csvFile:
      mydictionary.append(Server(row[0], row[1]))
      print("{}, {}".format(row[0], row[1]))

    return mydictionary

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    server_list = get_server_list('client_list.csv')
    dist_files(server_list, 'C:\\Users\\Public\\Test')
```

**client_list.csv**

> - 192.168.10.100, Test
> - 192.168.10.101, Test
> - 192.168.10.102, Test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Technical issues:**

- You are reading whole files into memory at once. Consider what happens if the directory contains huge files.
- You use `multiprocessing`, apparently in an attempt to parallelize things, and use locks to synchronize.
- First, why do you need a lock anyway? Which data do you want to protect? The only shared data are in the filesystems, which could be changed by other processes at any time anyway.
- Next, each call to `multi_distribute_file` gets its own lock instance, that is only used once by this call. So there is no synchronization happening at all.
- On the other hand, if you would use a single lock for all calls to `multi_distribute_file`, the processes will execute one after another, as each acquires the lock for its entire runtime. Your parallelizing efforts would be in vain.
- You are spawning a new process for each file being copied. This can create a **huge** number of processes very quickly. Consider what this will do to your system performance.
- If something goes wrong in `multi_distribute_file` and raises an exception, the lock will never be released. And things **will** go wrong occassionaly as you are communicating over a network. Use a `with` statement instead.
- Don't use string manipulation (`format` and `re`) to manipulate paths. Use `os.path` instead. This is saver and more reliable.

**Style issues**:

- There are no docstrings and no comments (apart from the header)
- Avoid single-letter and other abbreviated names like `d`, `l`, `m`, and `lo`.
- `mydictionary` is a meaningless and misleading name. Meaningless, as it doesn't tell us anything about the purpose of the variable, and misleading as it is actually a list, not a dictionary. A better name might be `server_list` (like you do elsewhere).